# Obtain IP Address from MAC using python

Tags: python, ip, scapy, mac-address

I have a device in my local network and know its MAC Address. It gets it's IP address automatically via DHCP. I want to obtain this IP.

I don't want to use nmap but scapy would be fine, as I'm importing from a kivy app.

I found:

```
from scapy.all import srp, Ether, ARP
ans,unans=srp(Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff")/ARP(pdst="192.168.1.0/24"),timeout=2)
```

and with

```
ans.summary()
```

I get the following output:

```
Ether / ARP who has 192.168.43.1 says 192.168.43.92 ==> Ether / ARP is at 3e:f8:d9:45:1b:3d says 192.168.43.1
```

My two problems are:

1: I have to run the script with sudo python and I'm not sure about the permissons in kivy.

2: Is there a simple way to get the variables for IP/MAC out of the .summary()?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can do that using scapy.  Here is an example of an ARP is-at packet:

```
###[ Ethernet ]###
  dst= 08:00:27:fa:25:8e
  src= 08:00:27:b1:af:68
  type= 0x806
    ###[ ARP ]###
     hwtype= 0x1
     ptype= 0x800
     hwlen= 6
     plen= 4
     op= is-at
     hwsrc= 08:00:27:b1:af:68
     psrc= 192.168.56.102
     hwdst= 08:00:27:fa:25:8e
     pdst= 192.168.56.101
        ###[ Padding ]###
            load= '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

You can assign the hwsrc and psrc values to a variable like this

```
srcMAC = pkt[ARP].hwsrc
srcIP = pkt[ARP].psrc
```

or just print them like this

```
print pkt[ARP].hwsrc
print pkt[ARP].psrc
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I can't upvote your answer. I got to little reputation :D

Answer (score -1):

If the stucture of summary is always the same (what I assume), then you could `import re` and use a regex to extract the IP address.

Should be something like:

```
re.sub(r'.* says (.*) ==> Ether / ARP is.*', r'\1', ans.summary())
```

That works for me:

```
>>> import re
>>> x = "Ether / ARP who has 192.168.43.1 says 192.168.43.92 ==> Ether / ARP is at 3e:f8:d9:45:1b:3d says 192.168.43.1"
>>> re.sub(r'.* says (.*) ==> Ether / ARP is.*', r'\1', x)
'192.168.43.92'
```

Comment: Thank u! I tried that but ans.summary() does not return a string or buffer:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
    re.sub(r'.* says (.*) ==> Ether / ARP is.*', r'\1', ans.summary())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: What datatype is ans.summary()?

Comment: Its a NoneType. Could the output come from a subprocess?