# Ping by MAC address using Python

Tags: python, macos, ping

How can I use Python to ping a device when I only know it's MAC address. I'm trying to build a system that pings a device every now and then to see if a device is currently connected to the network, but I don't want to ping by an IP address as they could very easily change (and no I don't want to statically assign addresses).

Comment: Why do you think this is possible? See [this](http://www.webune.com/forums/how-to-ping-by-mac-address.html) article for example.

Answer (score 1):

[Get IP address from MAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38182966/obtain-ip-address-from-mac-using-python) on the fly (every time you need to ping, re-calculate this) and then [ping the IP address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953462/pinging-servers-in-python).